# Is PHP Zip creation (overwrite) an atomic operation?

Tags: php, atomic, php-ziparchive

Our application overwrites an already existing ZIP file.
The zip file is downloadable, for ZIP creation we use PHP ZipArchive.

Now the question: 
Do I have to create a TMP ZIP file and rename it to the desired downloadable filename to have an atomic operation and all time access to a valid ZIP file, or is the ZIP creation process of ZipArchive already atomic?

Edit:
After testing it with multiple addFile calls, separated with a sleep, it seems like that the file is created / overwritten on the final close call. But the question remains, is the final ZIP file creation atomic?

Comment: I don't know but this may be easier than you think to test (and to fix).  Slow down the zipping process and try to access the file with another operation during the zipping; see if you get a corrupted file.

Comment: You have definitively right, but asking is faster as testing ;) Perhaps someone knows it already. If not, testing will be the last option.

Comment: I don't expect someone to test it for me... I am just asking.

Comment: @PaulCrovella better now?

Answer (score 0):

After testing it with a huge directory structure (the zip creation needed ~ 10seconds), and a "watch -n 0.1 unzip -t foo.zip" on the resulting ZIP file, it seems like that the ZIP file creation is atomic. 
At least I got no errors while testing the ZIP file.